# How to remove app from launcher (on a rooted device) programmatically

Tags: android, root, launcher

How can I remove an app from the launcher of an rooted device ?

Comment: Do you want to remove a launcher icon? Also, do you ask for a programmatic solution or `adb`'s one?

Comment: programmatic, added this to the title, sorry about the unclear title

Comment: The app still need to function? Does uninstall or disable the app satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Your app or an another app?

Comment: Yes it needs to function. I only want to hide it from the launcher.

Comment: All apps i want to

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what launcher you have, but maybe this will help:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.apphider&hl=en

http://tricksnow.com/how-to-hide-apps-on-android-with-root-and-without-root/

And if you want to uninstall bloatware apps:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zsj.android.systemappremover&hl=en

Comment: I search for an programmatic solution, added this to the title now, sorry for the unclear question

Answer (score 2):

i find this may it helps

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:com.domain.app");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide app icon from launcher we can do it in following way:

```
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class);     
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

To un-hide app icon from launcher we can do it in following way:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually from android 10+, it is quite difficult to hide the app launcher icon.
I have used the code of **@shridutt kothari**, just mentioned in the above comments.
When the disable code runs, it only make the app launcher icon disabled not hidden. But you cannot launch it, it open the app info setting page when click the launcher icon.

**Another way** -
This is another way to do that, make a app and run it as device owner mode.
Then we can able to hide/remove the app launcher icon.

**Visit the link-**
https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/dev-admin/uninstalling-and-disabling-apps